# CSS Isolation not working in my Empty Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Given:
BS 5.1
VS 2022 Pro

Do I need to configure something for CSS Isolation to work in my Empty Blazor Server App. I'm pretty sure BS is wired up because if I put a class directly in h1 tag, it works. I'm also using Hot Reload to make sure cache isn't the issue.

**Index.razor.cs**

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

**Index.razor.css**

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

**_Host.cshtml**

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace FpTakeANumberApp1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <base href="~/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    
        <div id="blazor-error-ui">
            <environment include="Staging,Production">
                An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
            </environment>
            <environment include="Development">
                An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
            </environment>
            <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
            <a class="dismiss"></a>
        </div>
    
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also share your `_Host.cshtml` code

Comment: updated OP.....

Comment: try adding `<link href="FpTakeANumberApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in the `<head>` section just after `<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: ok, that worked for me. If you add it as answer I'll mark it, also can you please help me understand how that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_Host.cshtml` page is missing the CSS isolation bundler stylesheet.

From the [MS docs for .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

> `<link href="{ASSEMBLY NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

So in your case it's

```
<link href="FpTakeANumberApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The blazor project templates after **.NET 6** are preconfigured with CSS isolation enabled.

I believe they only started adding CSS isolation from **.NET 5**. And you must be using one of the versions that isn't already preconfigured/pre-enabled so you have to enable it manually.